# lftp problem to upload files in runner gitlab-ci,yml

Tags: gitlab, ftp, lftp

this message return on upload file:

```
$ lftp -c "debug; set ftp:ssl-force true; set ssl:verify-certificate false; open -u $FTP_HOST_DEPLOY_USERNAME,$FTP_HOST_DEPLOY_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST_DEPLOY; mirror -Renv ./dist/app ./public_html"
```

---- Resolving host address...
---- IPv6 is not supported or configured
---- 1 address found: 145.14.145.229
---- Connecting to [MASKED] (145.14.145.229) port 21
**** Socket error (Operation timed out) - reconnecting
---- Closing control socket
---- Connecting to [MASKED] (145.14.145.229) port 21
**** Socket error (Operation timed out) - reconnecting
---- Closing control socket
---- Connecting to [MASKED] (145.14.145.229) port 21
**** Socket error (Operation timed out) - reconnecting
---- Closing control socket
---- Connecting to [MASKED] (145.14.145.229) port 21
**** Socket error (Operation timed out) - reconnecting
---- Closing control socket
---- Connecting to [MASKED] (145.14.145.229) port 21